# How to check if object is a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a function:

```
function Check(o)
{
    alert(/* o is a DOM element ? "true" : "false" */);
}
```

How can I check if the parameter `o` is a DOM object or not?

Comment: Any DOM node or a particular type of node?

Comment: @patrick Any. To check for a specific one I could just check the tagName right?

Comment: No, the `tagName` will give the type of a "type 1" element. There are several other types of nodes.

Comment: You can try/catch a DOM reserved function: ``function Check(n) { try { n.cloneNode() } catch(e) { return false; } return true }``

Answer (score 90, accepted):

A DOM element implements the `Element` interface. So you can use:

```js
function Check(o) {
    alert(o instanceof Element);
}
```

Comment: It's too bad it can't replace 'typeof' but it's because they're comparing different things (primitives vs object/constructor) in different ways. 'typeof' returns a unary operator vs 'instanceof' returns a binary (boolean) operator.

Comment: I did put upvote this answer in the past but something to note is this won't pass if validated by an Element class from a different context.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222237/instanceof-fails-in-iframe

So if this check don't work for you can try softer method like @Martin Jespersen

Answer (score 29):

Check if the `nodeName` property exists.

Basically check if it is a `Node`: look at the [DOM lvl 1 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/ecma-script-language-binding.html), check the Node definition.

If you meant it literally when you said `Element` check for `tagName` property, look at the Element definition in the same spec

So to recap, do either

```
function Check(o)
{
    alert(o.tagName ? "true" : "false");
}
```

to check if it is a DOM Element or

```
function Check(o)
{
    alert(o.nodeName ? "true" : "false" );
}
```

to check if it is a DOM Node

Comment: or `nodeType`, or whatever else is a property of the root `DOMElement` object.

Comment: This doesn't sound bullet-proof. What if there is an object with that property name? Is that the only way? I though there could be something else...

Comment: Well you can make it more secure by checking against all (or at least two or three) of the properties and methods those objects need to have to live up to the spec, but it seems like overkill...

Comment: @Martin No need for those quotes. Just use `true : false`

Comment: I know, but if you look at his specified code, quotes are there, I merely made his own code work.

Comment: `o instanceof Element` would be "safer" IMO

Comment: Let's see what happens when this object passes the test         {nodeName:"HACKINGERROR",tagName:"RORREGNIKCAH"}

Comment: @David It's also simpler, shorter, and easier to minify (no string literals). I think "duck typing" is fine at times, but only when significantly more elegant/compatible than the alternative. In this case, it isn't.

Comment: Wouldn't `return o&&o.tagName` be better? This is bad code.

Comment: @WillHoskings I agree, but if you look at the OPs question i merely made his own code work

Comment: You could offer a better altern, but ok. Rather not get caught up in this as I hate this site.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of just checking for the existence of a property, I'd check its specific value.

This assumes you're looking for a "type 1" element.

[`nodeType at MDC`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType)

```
function Check(o) {
    alert( o && o.nodeType && o.nodeType === 1 );
}
```

You could still get an object that has the `nodeType` property that isn't actually a DOM node, but it would also have to have a matching value of `1` to give a false positive.

Comment: A shorter version would be: obj && obj.nodeType === 1

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but a document fragment could be a node as well:

```
function isNode(node) {
    return node && (node.nodeType === 1 || node.nodeType == 11);
}
```

Credits: https://github.com/k-gun/so/blob/4.8.1/so.dom.js#L50

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function

```
function isNode(o)
{
  return o && 'nodeType' in o;
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be `'nodeType' in o`, but nice clean idea!

Comment: @BenRowe: Nate Barr is right, `'nodeType'` should be in quotes, if not, your code leads to _"ReferenceError: nodeType is not defined"_, so please edit your post!

Comment: Thanks, I'll make the adjustment

Comment: This will not check that the object is an element, it checks if it's a node. See Constantes section here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a DOM node is element with JQuery:

```
element.is("*")
```

Comment: How is that jQuery?