# Instanceof fails in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, instanceof

The following code returns `true`.

```js
console.log(document.createElement('script') instanceof Element);
```

---

Doing the same in an `<iframe>` context returns `false`:

```
let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
iframe = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

console.log(iframe.createElement('script') instanceof Element);
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Zenoo0/0ws5ptgc/)**

Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because:

1) `Element` is actually `window.Element`

2) In JS there is no such thing as a "class". Everything (almost) is an object. So instanceof checks for *Prototype ancestry*. When you ask `is some DOM node instanceof Element` you could kind of translate this to `someDOMNode.prototype === Element`.

3) `window.Element !== document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.Element` !!!

This will log `true` as expected:

```
console.log(iframe.createElement('script') instanceof  document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.Element);
```

Comment: That's .... not something I would have thought to check ... Thanks !